# SQLite - Arithmetic on columns from three different tables (sum, multiply, subtract, etc..)

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Using an SQLite query I'm trying to perform arithmetic with columns from different tables where I am multiplying prices of products in various groups by a percentage corresponding to each group in a separate table:

```
< Products Table >
Column Z  Column X Column Y
Product 1 Price 1  Delivery A
Product 2 Price 2  Delivery B
Product 3 Price 3  Delivery A
Product 4 Price 4  Delivery A
Product 5 Price 5  Delivery B
Product 6 Price 6  Delivery C

< Delivery Table >
Column O  Column P
Delivery A Warehouse A
Delivery B Warehouse A
Delivery C Warehouse B

< Warehouse Percentage Table >
Column M Column N
Warehouse A  Percentage A
Warehouse B  Percentage B

< Results Table / View >
Column E  Column F
Product 1 Total 1 (Price 1 * Percentage A)
Product 2 Total 2 (Price 2 * Percentage B
Product 3 Total 3 (Price 3 * Percentage A)
Product 4 Total 4 (Price 4 * Percentage A)
Product 5 Total 5 (Price 5 * Percentage B)
Product 6 Total 6 (Price 6 * Percentage B)
```

I have managed to work out how to perform arithmetic on columns from the same table which creates a new view:

```
SELECT id,
    SUM(column_a*column_b)
    FROM table_1
    GROUP BY id
```

I have also managed to join three tables:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_1
       INNER JOIN
       table_2 ON table_1.column_1 = table_2.column_1
       INNER JOIN
       table_3 ON table_2.column_2 = table_3.column_2;
```

But I cannot figure out how to perform arithmetic on two columns from two different tables joined by a third table such as:

`SUM(table_1.column_1*table_3.column_2)`

When I add this line of code to the query which joins all three tables I get:

`The SELECT statement could not be parsed. Please correct the query and retry.
Details: Syntax error`

Neither is there any way I can `INNER JOIN` `table_1` to `table_3` directly since they have no corresponding values so I have to join through `table_2`.

Comment: Well you first of all join the tables, and then access the columns from whichever is the appropriate source table …?

Comment: The same one you are using in the ON clause already ... `tablename.columnname`

Comment: Yes, of course addressing columns works the same way in this place, as any other.

Comment: Why are you using SUM? Does any table have multiple rows for one product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is quite simple but not if you are new to sql like myself:

```
SELECT table_1.price * table_3.percentage
       INNER JOIN
       table_2 ON table_1.column_1 = table_2.column_1
       INNER JOIN
       table_3 ON table_2.column_2 = table_3.column_2;
```

It seems like any arithmetic in sql needs to be done in the SELECT statement.

The more elaborate syntax for arithmetic below sent me on the wrong course when in fact the solution was a lot simpler:

```
SELECT id,
    SUM(column_a*column_b)
    FROM table_1
    GROUP BY id
```